# Does the photoelectric interaction occur mostly over the depletion zone of a photodiode?

Tags: photodiode

It is important for some photodiodes like the PIN diode to have a large depletion zone. This is to achieve a large area that allows for conversion of photons to electron-hole pairs.

Why does this happen?

The conversion occurs only in this zone? or does it occur everywhere but the charge can be collected only if it lays there?

Answer (score 2):

Charge carriers can be promoted any place light/radiation is allowed to fall on the material.  If this happens outside of a depletion zone, the bulk material will increase in conductivity.  If this happens inside a depletion zone, the charge will get swept out by the built-in and/or applied electric field.  If there is no external bias, the charge will "show up" as an increased voltage, which is what happens in solar cells.  If there is an external reverse bias, the charge will create an increase in conductivity but IIRC the SNR is much greater than for monolithic bulk material.

Answer (score 1):

A photon can knock an electron off of any material if it has sufficient energy. The question is, what does that electron do after it gets knocked off?

In the P an N regions the electron becomes free and either contributes to current conduction, but in the intrinsic region, it has a built up electric field so the hole and free electron will migrate away and create current.

Since the intrinsic layer is usually the widest layer in a PIN diode it contributes the most to current/conduction.

Comment: Interesting, that without a potential difference we can have current flow !

Comment: Interesting that the p and n junctions built in an electric field in the intrinsic layer, which contributes to conduction